# Return stdout from JS file run via Node

Tags: javascript, return, stdout

in our build process our main .js file runs several child .js files via Node to execute build tasks.

We need one child .js file to return data via `stdout` so that we can catch it in our main build script.

How can this be done ?

if we use `exec()` from `child_process` to run the child .js file and use the `return` statement to return data, `exec` never gets the data in it's `stdout` param.

If we use `spawn` from `child_process` we are able to catch `console.log` statements from the .js file, but not sure whether this is the only way and/or best method.... ?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: There is no best way to get the child_process's stdout. You can choose one of several possible methods depending on which one is better suited to your requirements.
However, it doesn't seem natural to run child.js using process in the main.js file. Why not import child.js and then call that module's function?